# How do I say, “that’s what you're supposed to do” in german?

Tags: translation, phrase

How do I say, “that’s what you're supposed to do” in german?

Comment: Welcome. The original sentence is missing a verb, so it would be hard to suggest a correct translation. Or are looking for an equally grammatically incorrect German sentence?

Comment: Welcome! Please specify what part or construction is of interest to you and what you already know.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward translation would be "Das ist Deine Aufgabe!" or "Das ist Dein Job!" or with slight more emphasis "Ja, das ist Deine Aufgabe!" if there was doubt that a certain job/task should be performed.